# What are the servers and database available for communication with android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am a beginner to android.I am developing an application in which my application will send some data to my server and the server will process it and send the result to my application.
 Please suggest any good server for communication with android and also a sample code for the communication with the server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options, but you can use Google App Engine with your android application.

See this video from Google I/O: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4

Answer (score 0):

A very wide question. You must understand that you can communicate with an Android device just like you can communicate with a regular computer so you kinda have a lot of options. That said if you want an easy solution I'd point you to [parse](https://parse.com/) which has an SDK for Android and a CMS backend which will handle everything from users and data management.